# Flutter not being able to locate Android Studio installation

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdkYI.png)

I tried everything but it was not useful
Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path
"".

Please verify that the path is correct and update it by running this command:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir '<path>'
```

To have Flutter search for Android Studio installations automatically, remove
the configured path by running this command:

```
 flutter config --android-studio-dir
```

The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and
diagnostic
data along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash
reports. This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework,
and related tools.

Telemetry is not sent on the very first run. To disable reporting of telemetry,
run this terminal command:

```
flutter --disable-analytics
```

If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent, and then no further
information will be sent. This data is collected by the Google
Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).

Please note that analytics reporting was already disabled, and will continue to
be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the path to your Android Studio installation.

Update the path using `flutter config --android-studio-dir '<path_to_android_studio>'`.

If you want Flutter to search for Android Studio installations automatically, remove the configured path with `flutter config --android-studio-dir ''`.

Disable telemetry data reporting with `flutter --disable-analytics`.